# How to publish transform from odom to base_link?

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, base-link, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Recorded rosbag file which contains Laserscan data (LMS100) linked to base_link. I trying to use amcl and localize the robot in the map, but amcl needs odom->baselink so that it can publish map->odom. But currently there is no link between odom and base_link.

I loaded the map in rviz, when set the **global options** to
*base_link -> I am getting scan data* ; when set to *odom -> I getting odometry data* in rviz; when set *map-> nothing* is happening. I want to integrate in the way map->odom->base_link.

I could not able to figure out the way to link the odom -> base_link. Can anyone help me to solve above problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105901/how-to-publish-transform-from-odom-to-base_link?/) by [Arunkumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/9316/arunkumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arunkumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/9316/arunkumar/) on 2013-11-29**:
Link to files as below:
"https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iezxmpehxs11qbl/4kVXtOGaU7"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no way you can do that without actual/simulated data. But, since you already have the laser data, the odometry data should be from the same 'run' as the laser data. That is, both should be in phase (or in time).

So without the odometry data I don't think you can use amcl. If you have odometry data on the topic say /odom. Then the rest is simple: write a node that reads the /odom topic and publishes whatever it reads on the odom topic as a transform from odom - base_link.

Look at this: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom

The only difference is you don't have to compute x, y and theta. They are already available in the odom message.

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2